# Hide or show div based on checkBox status

Tags: javascript, checkbox, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.2

How can you show or hide a div element based on a checkBox status in ASP.NET Core 2.2 with Razor?

I have this but it doesn't work:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#gridCheck1').change(function() {
        $('#ShowHideMe').toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
    });
});
</script>

<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">Checkbox</div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
                Example checkbox
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="ShowHideMe">
    <p>some content</p>
</div>
```

This is my library in the project folder :

[image]

Comment: `.toggle()` doesn't receive a boolean argument like that. Your code still more or less works, except that since the checkbox doesn't start out `checked`, the div is hidden when you check the box.

Comment: The div is shown when the application starts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seem working, if you want to start without showing the div add `style="display:none"` to it.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#gridCheck1').change(function() {
        $('#ShowHideMe').toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
    });
});
</script>

<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">Checkbox</div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
                Example checkbox
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="ShowHideMe" style="display:none">
    <p>some content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this works, is it the same with for example if you select some value in a dropdown list a div is shown?

Comment: Yes, it should work since you are listening for a `change` event