# Hide or show div based on checkBox status on load

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

This question is related to:

[Hide or show div based on checkBox status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58696846/hide-or-show-div-based-on-checkbox-status)

How to check if the checkbox is already checked on load.

I am using asp-for to load the content.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the checkbox is already checked on load.Try to use `$(function(){})`:

html:

```
<input type="checkbox" asp-for="gridCheck1" />
<div id="ShowHideMe">
    <p>some content</p>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(function () {
      myFunction();
 )};
 $('#gridCheck1').change(function () {
      myFunction();
 });
 function myFunction() {
     const div = document.getElementById('ShowHideMe');
     if ($("#gridCheck1").prop('checked')) {
          div.style.display = "block";
     } else {
          div.style.display = "none";
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

How i solved this, hope it helps :

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#gridCheck1').change(function() {

            myFunction();
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        myFunction();
    });

    function myFunction() {
        $('#ShowHideMe').toggle($('#gridCheck1').is(':checked'));
    }
</script>

<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">Checkbox</div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
                Example checkbox
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="ShowHideMe" style="display:none">
    <p>some content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).